# Scala exception NoClassDefFoundError: scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject in eclipse

Tags: json, scala

In my Scala program (in Eclipse IDE) I imported JSONObject as following:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject
```

When I tried to run the program it throws: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

But when I run mvn clean install, it can be compiled very well.
So I think maybe any tricks in the Eclipse, any idea please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try refreshing the eclipse project.

Comment: Try to clean build the eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sometimes gives problem with Scala. Try this -
Go to the eclipse toolbar.
Go to project.
Uncheck Build Automatically.
Go to Project again.
Select Build all. (It will force build the project).

Go to project again and check Build Automatically.